# How to return custom colors from a constructor

Tags: java, swing

For an assignment I need to have a "smiley" face be generated to be used in the main class for a JPanel, and it must use random colors. Obviously I can define the colors outside the constructor as I have done for testing my main code, but I want to know how to have it work within a constructor. The return statements give the error 'incompatable types: unexpected return value'.

```
public class Smiley extends JPanel
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    private int x = 5;
    private int y = 5;
    private int diameter = 200;

    // Smiley constructor takes parameters for 4 colors that will be used to draw the smiley
    public Smiley(Color outline, Color face, Color smile, Color eyes)
    {
        outline = new Color(rand.nextInt(256), rand.nextInt(256), rand.nextInt(256));
        face = new Color(rand.nextInt(256), rand.nextInt(256), rand.nextInt(256));
        smile = new Color(rand.nextInt(256), rand.nextInt(256), rand.nextInt(256));
        eyes = new Color(rand.nextInt(256), rand.nextInt(256), rand.nextInt(256));

        return outline; //this doesn't work.
        return face;
        return smile;
        return eyes;
    }

    // Use this method to draw the smiley face on the panel
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(outline);
        g.drawOval(x, y, diameter, diameter);

        g.setColor(face);
        g.fillOval(x+2, y+2, diameter-4, diameter-4);

        g.setColor(eyes);
        g.fillOval(x+25, y+66, diameter/3, diameter/3);
        g.fillOval(x+125, y+66, diameter/3, diameter/3);

        g.setColor(smile);
        g.fillArc(x+55, y+105, diameter/3, diameter/3, 180, 180);
    }
}
```

Comment: Return keyword in constructor will not work. It is illegal. You can set values of class member variables from within the constructor but this has nothing to do woth returning a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you still have to do is to create the colors as instance variables of your class. There is no need to retain a reference to the `Random` instance.

```
public class Smiley extends JPanel {
  private Color outline;
  private Color face;
  private Color smile;
  private Color eyes;

  public Smiley() {
     this(new Random());
  }

  public Smiley(Random rand) {
    outline = new Color(rand.nextInt(256), rand.nextInt(256), rand.nextInt(256));
    face = new Color(rand.nextInt(256), rand.nextInt(256), rand.nextInt(256));
    smile = new Color(rand.nextInt(256), rand.nextInt(256), rand.nextInt(256));
    eyes = new Color(rand.nextInt(256), rand.nextInt(256), rand.nextInt(256));
  }

 public Smiley(Color outline, Color face, Color smile, Color eyes) {
    this.outline = Objects.requireNonNull(outline);
    this.face = Objects.requireNonNull(face);
    this.smile = Objects.requireNonNull(smile);
    this.eyes = Objects.requireNonNull(eyes);
  }


  ...
}
```

The first (no-arg) constructor will create a smiley with random colors - and will create a new `Random` object each construction, the second constructor will create a smiley with random colors, allowing to pass a reusable `Random` object. The third constructor will allow to create a Smiley with the specified colors.

Answer (score 1):

Form Oracle Java Documentation:

> A class contains constructors that are invoked to create objects from the class blueprint. Constructor declarations look like method declarations—except that they use the name of the class and have no return type.

So it is impossible by concept to return a value from constructor.

Comment: Yes. Internally, the constructor returns `null`, but in practice, it returns the object you are creating. If you want to return other stuff, you need to make more fields on the class.